# Get the average out of an array of colors

Tags: java, colors

I was using various color utilities to mix in colors but due to an unorganised order it produces incorrect values. I've looked around and only found single colors or two color blends.

So instead I've placed the colors into an array and I'm currently trying to figure out how to blend them but now I'm stuck.

My attempt:

```
Array<Color> colorsArray;
for(Color eachColor : colors)
    colorsArray.add(new Color(
        eachColor.r, eachColor.g, eachColor.b,
        strength //<<Varies.
    );
));

/We have an array of play colors and there strengths, process them into an average.
float totalRed = 0f, totalBlue = 0f, totalGreen = 0f;
for(ColorStorage colorStorage : colorVectorsWithInfectionStrength)
{
    totalRed += (colorStorage.getRed() * colorStorage.getAlpha());
    totalBlue += (colorStorage.getBlue() * colorStorage.getAlpha());
    totalGreen += (colorStorage.getGreen() * colorStorage.getAlpha());
}

/* Makes dark colors. HMM.
totalRed /= colorVectorsWithInfectionStrength.size;
totalBlue /= colorVectorsWithInfectionStrength.size;
totalGreen /= colorVectorsWithInfectionStrength.size;
*/

ColorStorage averageColor = new ColorStorage(totalRed, totalBlue, totalGreen);

//varying var goes from 0-1 depending on the max strength.
endColor = ColorUtils.blend(averageColor, endColor, varyingVar);
```

And the blend function:

```
public static ColorStorage blend(ColorStorage color1, ColorStorage color2, double ratio)
{
    float r  = (float) ratio;
    float ir = (float) 1.0 - r;

    float rgb1[] = color1.getColorComponents();
    float rgb2[] =  color2.getColorComponents();

    return new ColorStorage (
        rgb1[0] * r + rgb2[0] * ir,
        rgb1[1] * r + rgb2[1] * ir,
        rgb1[2] * r + rgb2[2] * ir
    );
}
```

*EDIT*
The color object here is custom that always returns 0-1f for RGBA. (Each value)

Comment: Why you have commented the part, where you are dividing?

Comment: Because it produces dark results that are incorrect.

Comment: Based on my very sketchy knowledge of colour spaces I'm not entirely sure this method of blending works. Though the actual `blend()` method will indeed sweep through a colour curve between `color1` and `color2` as you move `ratio` from 0 to 1. But if you have an alpha channel, combining more than 2 colours can become tricky.

Comment: Indeed I've come to realise, there must be a solution!

Comment: Is the `colorsArray` part of your code really necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried dividing by the array size and it produced colours that were too dark. That's due to the fact that you multiply each component by the alpha value (and not 1, like you would without an alpha channel). If you want to normalize the colours correctly, you need to divide by the sum of alphas.

```
float totalAlpha = 0;
for(ColorStorage colorStorage : colorVectorsWithInfectionStrength)
{
    totalRed += (colorStorage.getRed() * colorStorage.getAlpha());
    totalBlue += (colorStorage.getBlue() * colorStorage.getAlpha());
    totalGreen += (colorStorage.getGreen() * colorStorage.getAlpha());
    totalAlpha += colorStorage.getAlpha();
}

totalRed /= totalAlpha;
totalBlue /= totalAlpha;
totalGreen /= totalAlpha;
```

This should give you the correct scale.

Please note though that it won't give you an accurate blend either because the RGB colour space isn't linear. But it's close enough for casual use.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks so much. Just running it though some tests.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns You should also check whether `totalAlpha` is 0, to avoid divide by zero issues.

Comment: Thanks for the pro-tip :-)